# Using Metalama. how do you get the methods line number and include it in the stringbuilder

Tags: metalama

The subject says it all.
Using OverrideMethodAspect.

I've been using Postsharp for many years and am trying to convert to Metalama.

Comment: The source file and line number are not exposed in Metalama at the moment. What is your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Metalama 2023.3 or later, you can do:

```cs
meta.Target.Declaration.Sources.SingleOrDefault( x => x.IsImplementationPart ).Span
```

The returned object gives you the file and line number.